# Solve motion equations for first ODE using scipy

Tags: numpy, scipy, ode, runge-kutta

I would like to solve motion first order ODE equations using scipy solve_ivp function. I can see that I'm doing something wrong because this should be an ellipse but I'm plotting only four points. Are you able to spot the mistake?

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import scipy.integrate


gim = 4*(math.pi**2)
x0 = 1 #x-position of the center or h
y0 = 0 #y-position of the center or k
vx0 = 0 #vx position
vy0 = 1.1* 2* math.pi #vy position
initial = [x0, y0, vx0, vy0] #initial state of the system
time = np.arange(0, 1000, 0.01) #period

def motion(t, Z): 
  dx = Z[2] # vx
  dy = Z[3] # vy
  dvx = -gim/(x**2+y**2)**(3/2) * x * Z[2]
  dvy = -gim/(x**2+y**2)**(3/2) * y * Z[3]
  return [dx, dy, dvx, dvy]

sol = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(motion, t_span=time, y0= initial, method='RK45')
plt.plot(sol.y[0],sol.y[1],"x", label="Scipy RK45 solution")
plt.show()
```

[image: The plot i get]

[image: The plot i am aiming for]

Comment: I don't think you've posted the exact code you're using: `x` and `y` are not defined in `motion`. `solve_ivp` argument `t_span` expects the end points of the time interval (i.e., two numbers).  Finally, what is this modelling?  Having dvx depend on vx (and similarly for dvy) introduces damping, which I don't *think* will produce an ellipse; the equations are nonlinear though, so it's difficult to say.

Answer (score 0):

The code should not be able to run from a fresh workspace. The variables `x,y` that are used in the gravitation formula are not declared anywhere. So insert the line `x,y = Z[:2]` or similar.

The gravitation formula usually does not contain the velocity components. Remove `Z[2]`, `Z[3]`.

Check again what the time span and evaluation times arguments expect. The time span takes the first two values from the array. So change to `t_span=time[[0,-1]]` to build the pair of first and last time value.

The second plot suffers from insufficient evaluation points, the line segments used are too large. With your `time` array that should not be a problem.